# php preg_replace words last part

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
$str='<p>http://domain.com/1.html?u=1234576</p><p>http://domain.com/2.html?u=2345678</p><p>http://domain.com/3.html?u=3456789</p><p>http://domain.com/4.html?u=56789</p>';
$str = preg_replace('/.html\?(.*?)/','.html',$str);
echo $str;
```

I need get

```
<p>http://domain.com/1.html</p>
<p>http://domain.com/2.html</p>
<p>http://domain.com/3.html</p>
<p>http://domain.com/4.html</p>
```

remove `?u=*number*` from every words last part. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$str = preg_replace('/.html\?(.*?)/','.html',$str);
```

into this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/.html\?(.*?)</','.html<',$str);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the other answers:

```
preg_replace("/<p>([^?]*)\?[^<]*<\/p>/", "<p>$1</p>", $input);
```

This will match all types of urls with url variables, not only the ones with html-files in them.

For example, you can also extract these types of values:

```
<p>http://domain.com/1.php?u=1234576</p>
<p>http://domain.com?u=1234576</p>
<p>http://domain.com</p>
<p>http://domain.com/pages/users?uid=123</p>
```

With an output of:

```
<p>http://domain.com/1.php</p>
<p>http://domain.com</p>
<p>http://domain.com</p>
<p>http://domain.com/pages/users</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will load the url's into an array so they can be handled on the fly:

```
$str = '<p>http://domain.com/1.html?u=1234576</p><p>http://domain.com/2.html?u=2345678</p><p>http://domain.com/3.html?u=3456789</p><p>http://domain.com/4.html?u=56789</p>';
$str = str_replace("<p>","",$str);
$links = preg_split('`\?.*?</p>`', $str,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

foreach($links as $v) {
    echo "<p>".$v."</p>";
}
```